# Tkinter Canvas Opposite of delete

Tags: python, tkinter

Every Item of Tkinter Canvas widget has a unique item id. I can delete the item by using

```
canvas.delete(itemId)
```

Now how do I get back the item on the Canvas assuming I have kept the itemId intact?

```
canvas.add(itemId) # something like this but add is not a canvas method
```

I read that it can be done in Tcl/Tk but did not find any equivalent reference for tkinter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Canvas widget has no `add` method, but the different `create_` methods. If you have already deleted an item and you want to "restore" it, you should get the options of the item before that and then create a new one with the values you have retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete it, it's gone. You can't get it back. The item id is just an identifier, not an actual object.

Comment: Can you please look at this article http://wiki.tcl.tk/15181 where they have implemented undo/redo on canvas using the id it seems ?

Comment: @QuakiGabbar: well, of course you can _implement_ undo and redo. The fact remains, when you delete a canvas item it is gone for good. If you want to undo, it is up to you to save the information necessary to recreate the object.